# "Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients." when calling from another sub

Tags: vba, excel

After reading through many questions with this same title, I am still struggling to prevent the error in the title from occurring when my code runs.

The code begins here:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Toggle_Click()

    Dim lngMoveBy As Long
    Dim Loop1 As Long
    Dim intShapeNumber As Integer

    intShapeNumber = Right(Application.Caller, Len(Application.Caller) - Len("Toggle"))
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then Toggle_ErrorPrevention intShapeNumber
```

Then moves to this Sub in the same module:

```
Sub Toggle_ErrorPrevention(ByVal intShapeNumberVal As Integer)

    Dim lngHLSegmentNumberingRow As Long
    Dim lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow As Long
    Dim lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow As Long


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Columns(1)
        lngHLSegmentNumberingRow = .Find(What:="HL Segment Numbering", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row
```

before failing on the final line above, `lngHLSegmentNumberingRow = .Find(What:="HL Segment Numbering", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row`, with "Automation error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients."

If I save and close the document after the error occurs and restart it, Column 1 on the "Correction Type Options" sheet is highlighted.

This is my first time calling subs from other subs, so I've been paying extra attention to the call itself as a potential source of the problem. I'm still not confident it's correct.

---

Here is the complete module, in case it helps:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Toggle_Click()

    Dim lngMoveBy As Long
    Dim Loop1 As Long
    Dim intShapeNumber As Integer

    intShapeNumber = Right(Application.Caller, Len(Application.Caller) - Len("Toggle"))
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then Toggle_ErrorPrevention intShapeNumber

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
        lngMoveBy = 0.6
    Else
        lngMoveBy = -0.6
    End If

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("Toggle" & intShapeNumber)
        For Loop1 = 1 To 24
            .IncrementLeft lngMoveBy
            DoEvents
        Next Loop1
    End With

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber)
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "On"
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
            .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    Else
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Shapes("ToggleBackground" & intShapeNumber)
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Off"
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Bold = True
            .TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 1
            .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
    End If

End Sub

Sub Toggle_ErrorPrevention(ByVal intShapeNumberVal As Integer)

    Dim lngHLSegmentNumberingRow As Long
    Dim lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow As Long
    Dim lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow As Long


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Columns(1)
        lngHLSegmentNumberingRow = .Find(What:="HL Segment Numbering", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow = .Find(What:="Claim Removal - Have Wanted Claims", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row
        lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow = .Find(What:="Claim Removal - Have Unwanted Claims", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options")
        If intShapeNumberVal + 1 = lngHLSegmentNumberingRow Then
            If .Shapes("ToggleBackground" & lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow - 1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then Application.Run .Shapes("Toggle" & lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow - 1).OnAction
            If .Shapes("ToggleBackground" & lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow - 1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then Application.Run .Shapes("Toggle" & lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow - 1).OnAction
        End If
        If intShapeNumberVal + 1 = lngClaimRemovalHaveWantedClaimsRow Then
            If .Shapes("ToggleBackground" & lngHLSegmentNumberingRow - 1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then Application.Run .Shapes("Toggle" & lngHLSegmentNumberingRow - 1).OnAction
        End If
        If intShapeNumberVal + 1 = lngClaimRemovalHaveUnwantedClaimsRow Then
            If .Shapes("ToggleBackground" & lngHLSegmentNumberingRow - 1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0) Then Application.Run .Shapes("Toggle" & lngHLSegmentNumberingRow - 1).OnAction
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This error seems to have more to do with compatibility between versions of Excel (from a very brief search). Search this site with your error as the search term and you will see a number of different possible causes & solutions

Comment: So what have you tried/ eliminated? I'll warn you though, it might be difficult for us to help if it seemingly has little to do with the code (as per the other solutions!)

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using? Also, I'd advise posting the rest of your code

Comment: @CallumDA Good question. I'm using Office Professional Plus 2013/Excel 2013 on Windows 7 Enterprise. I edited the complete module into my question.

Comment: @CallumDA I just found out that original error was occurring because `Toggle_ErrorPrevention` was running successfully the first time, but then calling attempting to call `Toggle_Click` via the `.OnAction` lines in `Toggle_ErrorPrevention` did not update the `Application.Caller` in `Toggle_Click`. What I'm trying to do is turn off Option 1 if someone turns on Option 2 or 3 and vice versa because they're not compatible. Is it possible to run a second, and this may be the wrong word, instance of `Toggle_Click` while the first instance is still mid-execution?

Comment: From what I understand, that doesn't sound possible. It might be worth explaining the new issue in a new question - but include screenshots of what you are trying to achieve. It sounds like a bit of refactoring might be necessary

Comment: @CallumDA If I originally start `Toggle_Click` by clicking Option 2 while Option 1 is already on, it successfully sees that Option 1 is already on and triggers `Toggle_ErrorPrevention`. Then `Toggle_ErrorPrevention` triggers `Toggle_Click` programatically so Option 1 can be turned off. I try to have the new `Application.Caller` be registered as Option 1 (so it can be turned off), but Excel shows it as Option 2 even though it is run successfully from a line that equates to `.Shapes(Option 1).OnAction`

Comment: Hey, I've tried to understand the ins and outs of your code but it really is difficult without seeing your workbook/ playing around with the file myself. Using `Application.Caller` isn't usually a good way to pass arguments to your routines (I wouldn't want to suggest a better way without seeing your setup). I imagine a bit of refactoring would be the way to go if you can't work out a fix. Apologies I can't be more help :(

Comment: @CallumDA That's okay! I'm sorry my code is messy - I'm working hard to become more professional but I still have several bad habits. I'm going to take this feedback you just gave me to add comments to the code in the new question I just asked to try to make things clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I realise this is a long shot...*

This error seems to pop up at unusual times and one (semi) recurring solution is to deal with objects in the best way possible. So try this:

```
Sub Toggle_ErrorPrevention(ByVal intShapeNumberVal As Integer)

    Dim findRange As Range
    Dim lngHLSegmentNumberingRow As Long
    'more declarations

    Set findRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Columns(1).Find(What:="HL Segment Numbering", Lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        lngHLSegmentNumberingRow = findRange.Row
    End If

    'other code...
End Sub
```

You would have got *an error* if `.Find` returned nothing, because you can't get the `Row` property of `Nothing`.

Comment: The longshot worked, thank you. I had seen warnings on other questions to make sure everything was properly qualified to prevent this error, so I tried making sure that my line was fully, _fully_ qualified by using `lngHLSegmentNumberingRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Correction Type Options").Columns(1).Find(What:="HL Segment Numbering", Lookat:=xlWhole).Row`, but that didn't work. For whatever reason, saving it to an object first works. Thanks again.

Comment: @puzzlepiece87 you were absolutely right to *fully, fully* qualify any reference to a workbook/worksheet/range etc. Keep doing that in the future and you'll save yourself from a lot of potential errors. The main thing here is recognising that `.Find` returns either a `Range` (if it finds something) or `Nothing` (if it doesn't find anything). You can't perform `.Row` to `Nothing` so you have to check for that first. This is a useful thing to remember for any method that returns a range object.